# Angular 8 passing dynamic data into activated route in a (list detail) kind of setup

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that shows a list of products and by using a service and once you click an item on the list i'm able to redirect to the individual item using the `/:id` parameter on my routes, but what i'm really not getting is how to display the product properties like the name and the price in the product detail component. Is there a way to pass the data using using the routing module or do i have to use `output()` and `input()` ?

Comment: Is it redirected from component or HTML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the data to route either of the following two ways.
1. If the `route` is redirected from `component` use the following method.

```
this.router.navigate(['/<route-url>'], { state: { data: { <your-data>} } });
```

2. If the `route` is redirected from `HTML Template` use the following method.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/<route-url>']" [state]="{ data: { <your-data>} }">
  link to user component
</a>
```

From the `component` you can get the passed data using `location` object

Comment: Does this method work with dynamic data? and is it a really an ideal solution for instance for long pieces of text like the product description?

Comment: Yes it works for dynamic data as well and the state object can accept character limit upto 640K( this is for Firefox). If you are really worried about text size please consider input() and output() method.